# Save image into an output folder

Tags: matlab, save

Following code plots white dots on the overlay image (because of "hold on;"). I know how to save the overlay image in the output folder but I want to save the overlay image after "white dots" are plotted on the overlay image.

```
b = imadjust(mat2gray(BLUE));
z = zeros(size(b),'like',b);
b = cat(3,z,z,b);
O = bwperim(maskBLUE);
T= imdilate(O, true(2));
overlay = imoverlay(b, T, [1 1 1]);
imshow(overlay)
hold on;
plot(centersBLUE(:,1),centersBLUE(:,2),'.w')
h = overlay;
imwrite(h,[outputFolder]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should save all the graphs in one go:

```
h = get(0,'children');
for i=1:length(h)
  saveas(h(i), ['Overlaydots' num2str(length(h)+1-i)], 'jpg');
end
```

Just leave the graph windows open.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but in the saved image, the dots are black, however, I defined it in the plot as '.w' which is white dots. Is it possible to save it with white dots as it is in the code?

Comment: Do the dots need to be white? Could you try another color? It might be a Matlab error. It doesn't want to keep track of white points seen the background is white. This might be just speculation.

Comment: Thanks so much, I changed it to green.